# AttributeError 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error that says:

### AttributeError at /series/

'int' object has no attribute 'get'

I don't know why and what is causing this error
My models.py

```
class Series(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    SeriesName = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
    NoEpisodes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    EpisodesWatched = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    CoverImage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Series"
```

My views.py:

```
def seriesview(request):
    form = SeriesForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SeriesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # error raised here
            print("Form is valid")
    return render(request, 'series.html', {'form': form})
```

My forms.py:

```
class SeriesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Series
        fields = ('SeriesName', 'NoEpisodes', 'EpisodesWatched', 'CoverImage')
        labels = {
            "SeriesName": "Series Name:",
            "NoEpisodes": "Number of episodes:",
            "EpisodesWatched": "Episodes watched:",
            "CoverImage": "Add a cover image:",
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SeriesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            if visible.field.widget.input_type == 'file':
                visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control-file'
                continue
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def clean(self):
        episodes = self.cleaned_data['NoEpisodes']
        episodeswatched = self.cleaned_data['EpisodesWatched']
        if episodeswatched > episodes or episodes < episodeswatched:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Error creating series, Episodes watched can\'t be greater than number of episodes')
        return episodeswatched
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\JK\Dev\Project\AET\AnimeX\views.py", line 70, in seriesview
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 386, in _post_clean
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 346, in _get_validation_exclusions
    field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and one line is highlighted by django when I get the error:

```
if form.is_valid(): # this line is in views.py
```

If you need any other information comment below

Comment: I think it will be useful if you post the traceback of the error. Also, if available, post the code of the `get_method()` being called.

Comment: @fountainhead I have posted the traceback but i don't have any get_method() this error occurs when I submit the form

Answer (score 0):

following djnango manual:

> By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial individual field checks.

so fallowing your example you have get method in:

```
def clean(self):
    episodes = self.cleaned_data['NoEpisodes'] # here
    episodeswatched = self.cleaned_data['EpisodesWatched'] # and here 
    if episodeswatched > episodes or episodes < episodeswatched:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Error creating series, Episodes watched can\'t be greater than number of episodes')
    return episodeswatched
```

propably after clean_NoEpisodes or clean_EpisodesWatched one of those fields are empty. (they didn't pass field validation).

in manual there is call for super.clean() so i wolud try something like:

```
 def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    print(cleaned_data) # to see all fields in console
    episodes = cleaned_data.get('NoEpisodes')
    episodeswatched = cleaned_data.get('EpisodesWatched')
    # and then magic
```

Comment: I removed `return episodeswatched` and it worked!, `print(cleaned_data)` is printing all all fields with values correctly Thanks! you gave me some insights.